# SQL Server 2016 RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server 2016 Standard Version and often face with

```
RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT
```

wait types. However my server CPU don't exceed 20% and I have always 75 GB freeable memory?

I set MAXDOP value 3 but there is no change. I didn't face with any problem when I was using Enterprise edition with same DB and same queries.

Thank you for help

Comment: are you having performance issues or just seeing the wait types?

Comment: Yes I have performance isseus. One of my query sometimes wait 20 seconds. However It was solved after I updatestats.

Answer (score 1):

We exerienced the same today and it was due to a virtualization issue.
We had another VM on the same physical host which ran at 100% CPU and due to overcommitment and missing reservation, the Database VM had to wait for CPU cycles. This is almost impossible to track down from within the Database VM.